# How do I store a number of data in an input field so that I can access the data on event as event.target.value or event.target.name?

Tags: reactjs

I have an input field like so:

```
<input name="name" id="name" onChange(event => onChange(event)) />
```

I can use input properties like name, id or ref fields to store data in the input field so that on input `onChange`, in order to be able to perform the following.

```
onChange(event)
{
  data = this.state.data;
  data[event.target.id] = event.target.id
  this.setState({ data });
}
```

What if I have many values to store in the input field? Is it possible to set an object with multiple values in the input field? For e.g. if id could be an object, I could do something like, `event.target.id.name`, `event.target.id.age`, `event.target.id.address`. I'm aware that id is not the correct property to store multiple data. However, I'm  not sure id or any other property of an input can store an object.

```
data[event.target.property] = event.target.property
```

What is the correct approach to this?

Comment: I can think of calling `onChange` with multiple parameters:
`onChange(event => onChange(event, object1, object2, object3, "Some String", SomeInt)`. But I guess you want something smoother.

Comment: That actually a good idea. Thanks a lot, mate.

Comment: I could see why you want only event to pass. This way you could use only one `onChange`. Maybe someone else knows a smoother/better solution. Anyway, no problem